# JPA2 -- Where is EntityManager.detach?

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, detach

I read in several places that JPA2 will support a detach method call on Entity Manager.  I am running with Hibernate 3.5.1-FINAL and Spring 3.0.2-RELEASE as Maven dependencies -- snagged from the JBoss repository.

Isn't this enough?

Perhaps the problem is with my javax.persistence.EntityManager interface definition.  Do I need to update javax?  How does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  My maven project (at the top level) had a dependency on javax.persistence persistence-api 1.0.  I took this out and replaced it with hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.FINAL and viola...i have detach!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to declare hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.FINAL as dependency, you get it transitively from hibernate-entitymanager 3.5.1.Final. Running `mvn dependency:tree` would confirm this.

Comment: You are right, but I have hibernate-entitymanager as a runtime scope dependency just to be extra sure I don't have any hibernate specific code.  THerefore I needed to declare the api as a compile scope dependency.